# Using printf to align numbers and headings in a table

Tags: java, formatting, printf

I have never properly understood how printf works and could really use some formatting help. I want my printed output to look like this:

```
Student     Correct      Incorrect
   1           3             7
   2           4             6
   3           8             2
```

So on and so forth. I just can't figure out the proper way to format my printf statement to achieve this. This is what I have as far as a statement:

```
System.out.println ((studentAns.indexOf(ans) + 1) + "\t" + correct + "\t" + incorrect);
```

And this is what I have for the headings:

```
for (String heading : headings)                
  {
     System.out.printf ("%8s\t", heading);
  }
```

It maintains even spacing as far as the numbers go, but doesn't align with the headings. New programmer here - all your help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: if your headings as longer than a "tab stop" it will fail. Lookup how to do fixed width fields with printf.

Comment: Please accept answers if they help you out. You have not accepted any of the answers to the 5 questions you've asked so far.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach to align things in your table,

```
// This will create a String of `i` spaces.
private static String getSpaces(int i) {
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  for (int t = 0; t < i; t++) {
    sb.append(' ');
  }
  return sb.toString();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  String[] heading = new String[] { "Student",
      "Correct", "Incorrect" };
  int[][] data = new int[][] {
      new int[] { 1, 3, 7 }, new int[] { 2, 4, 6 },
      new int[] { 3, 8, 2 } };
  System.out.printf("%10s %10s %10s\n", heading[0],
      heading[1], heading[2]);
  for (int[] arr : data) {
    // Shift each data element right by the half the heading string length
    System.out.printf("%10s %10s %10s\n",
        String.valueOf(arr[0])
            + getSpaces(heading[0].length() / 2),
        String.valueOf(arr[1])
            + getSpaces(heading[1].length() / 2),
        String.valueOf(arr[2])
            + getSpaces(heading[2].length() / 2));
  }
}
```

Output is

```
 Student    Correct  Incorrect
    1          3         7    
    2          4         6    
    3          8         2
```